# FlowRouter defaulted redirect to the landing page

Tags: meteor, url-routing, redirect, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am trying to have protected routes like these: `1). loggedin user group routes 2.) admin routes, 3.) student routes, 4.) public routes`. The `LoggedInUser` works as expected but the 2 other routes - `schooladmin` and `students` does not work as needed.

After logging in as an admin or as a student, according to the expectation the respective users should be able to go to the allowed urls but whenever, as an example, if a schooladmin admin goes to http://localhost/students it automatically redirects back to dashboard, and likewise for student. What am I to do right?

This route group allows only logged in users.

```
var LoggedInUser = FlowRouter.group({
  name: 'currentUser', triggersEnter: [function (context, redirect) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId()) {
      FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
      let currentRoute = FlowRouter.current();
      if (!currentRoute.path) {
        FlowRouter.go('/dashboard');
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go(currentRoute.path);
      }

    } else {
      redirect('/');
    }
  }]
});
```

This is the route group for school admins

```
var schooladmin = LoggedInUser.group({
  name: 'schooladmins', triggersEnter: [function (context, redirect) {
    FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
    let currentRoute = FlowRouter.current();
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['super-admin', 'admin'])) {
      console.log(currentRoute.path);
      FlowRouter.go(currentRoute.path);
    } else {
      redirect('dashboard');
    }
  }]
});
```

This is the route for students

```
var students = LoggedInUser.group({
  name: 'students', triggersEnter:[function (context, redirect) {
    FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
    let currentRoute = FlowRouter.current();
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['manage-team', 'student-page'])) {
      FlowRouter.go(currentRoute.path);
    } else {
      redirect('dashboard');
    }
  }]
});
```

Sample routes the groups are attached to
This sample route is for school admins only to access

```
schooladmin.route('/students', {
  name: 'students', action(){
    BlazeLayout.render('formrender', {formrend: 'student'});
  }
});
```

this route is for student to access

```
students.route('/student/dashboard', {
  name: 'students-dashboard', action(){
    BlazeLayout.render('studentlayout', {studentrender: 'studentdashboard'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Roles package actually depends on a subscription, which means that if the subscription is not ready the `Roles.userIsInRole` method will always return `false`. And then your route fails, because FlowRouter always runs no matter what. This happens in very specific cases, but it happens and your users will notice.

Fortunately there is now a fix. We can have full control over when FlowRouter initializes.

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1. Just above FlowRouter Declaration use `Accounts.onLogin(function(user){});` method to check role and then redirect. (check user._id for Roles)
2. Click here for second solution https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42